# Does a domain restriction impact continuity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity, proof-writing

Suppose I have a function $F$ that is continuous on $\mathbb R$, and suppose that I have a function $G$ that is equal to $F$ on $\mathbb R$\{$a$}, for some fixed point $a \in \mathbb R$.

Given this, will $G$ be continuous? How could you prove/disprove $G$'s continuity?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ a \}$ the domain of $G$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know some basic topology. It is easy to see $G$ is continuous.

Let $D = \mathbb{R} - a$ and $D$ inherits the topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $F \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. For any open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R$, 
\begin{align*}
G^{-1}(U) = (F|_D)^{-1} (U) = F^{-1}(U) \cap D.
\end{align*}
$F^{-1}(U) \cap D$ is open in the subspace topology, so $G$ is continuous.

Comment: im in a first year calculus course so assume i dont know any topology :)

Comment: You can also think continuity pointwise. Since $F$ is continuous at every point, $G$ should be continuous at all points except $\{a\}$. But $G$ is not defined at $\{a\}$. This means $G$ is continuous in every point in its domain and thus continuous.